# Ordering TableViews by latest time

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, sorting

Currently I am having trouble ordering my table views in the right order. As of right now, they don't change order no matter what. I'm not sure what to add to fix this.

```
import UIKit

class ListNotesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var notes = [Note](){
        didSet{
            tableView.reloadData();
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notes = CoreDataHelper.retrieveNotes()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notes.count;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath : IndexPath) ->ListNotesTableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listNotesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ListNotesTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        let note = notes[row]
        cell.noteTitleLabel.text = note.title
        cell.notePreview.text = note.content;
        cell.noteModificationTimeLabel.text = note.modificationTime?.convertToString()
        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            if identifier == "displayNote" {
                print("Table view cell tapped")

                let indexPath =  tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
                let note = notes[indexPath.row]
                let displayNoteViewController = segue.destination as! DisplayNoteViewController
                displayNoteViewController.note = note

            } else if identifier == "addNote" {
                print("+ button tapped")
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {

            CoreDataHelper.delete(note: notes[indexPath.row])

            notes = CoreDataHelper.retrieveNotes()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToListNotesViewController(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        self.notes = CoreDataHelper.retrieveNotes()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not sorting during the CoreData fetch?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `notes` is not sorted by time. Whenever you get  `self.notes = CoreDataHelper.retrieveNotes()` you need to sort your array. You can do it like this:

```
self.notes.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
```

**Note** that the `date` variable can differ depending on what variable name you have for your time and structure on your `Note` class.